# Is it possible to connect a flutter app to a laser printer via Bluetooth/LAN/Wifi and also add another printer dynamically?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, printing, sdk

I am not able to find any SDK to connect the printer to a flutter app.

I tried to connect a HP LaserJet Pro MFP M226dw printer to a flutter app but there is no SDK available in https://developers.hp.com/tools.Is there any other ways to connect any other printers dynamically to a flutter app?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) package if you're developing with flutter.
Assuming your printer has some form of Networking capabilities, make sure it is connected to the same network as your device and the Default Print Service will usually take care of it.